# hide body (html) scroll in angular 2/4

Tags: css, angular, scrollbar

I'm attempting to hide the body (html) scrollbar.
adding:

```
body,
html{
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Both in the component css file or in "app.component.css" does not seems to help.
Any Ideas?

Edit:
Adding the above to "styles.css" file instead (which is called via .angular-cli.json) seems to work. I am still curios the know why it does not work when placed at the component or "app-component" css files..

Answer (score 1):

This might work, because it prevents view emulation which rewrites the selectors so that only elements within the comopnents template are addressed

```
* ::ng-deep body,
* ::ng-deep html{
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console? What's the resulting CSS in the browsers devtools? Can you create a Plunker to reproduce the issue?

Comment: no errors. i cant see my the added styles for the body in the devtools, it only inherits from bootstrap..

Comment: How do the styles added to body look like? I can't debug from here why they are not applied even when you confirm that they are added.

Comment: adding the original css commands to styles.css file seems to work. i have no idea why putting it in the other files did not..

Comment: Probably because the one is the global css file added to `index.html` unchanged, and component styles are rewritten for style encapsulation purposes. If you don't have the latest Angular 4 version, try `/deep/` instead of `::ng-deep` with the suggested change from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
@Component({
...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
....
})
```

in app.component.ts along with import ViewEncapsulation.

Might help